# Get Request from WCF Rest service

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, rest

I added a WCF Library Project(A) to an existing project(B). Project B initiates the WCF service(A), and can also stop it.

```
 restSvc = new ServiceHost(typeof(RestServiceSvc.RestEndPoint));
 restSvc.Open();
```

WCF service (A) has one POST, and I want to pass this information to project (B).
project B can be Form Application, but not necessarily. I have no clue on where to start. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor you chose will always create a new service instance. You cannot influence that. Instead, create your own instance, so you can pass something in when you create it. It's up to you what you pass. A callback, your Form instance, additional data, anything you want:

```
var service = new RestServiceSvc.RestEndPoint();

// obviously, you need to implement anything you may want to pass
// you could also pass this in the constructor of your service class
// You can access these properties in your service methods.
service.YourCustomProperty = someDataYouNeed;
service.YourCallBack = () => YourForm.FunctionCall();

restSvc = new ServiceHost(service);
restSvc.Open();
```

Comment: I think OP is asking how to create a client that calls the service.

Comment: @Crowcoder I don't think so. His project B is the *hosting* project and he wants to pass information from the service to the hosting project.